# Rewrite to subdomain and rewrite again there

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have  `/` and `/sub` on my webspace.
The subdomain `sub.example.com` takes his data from `/sub`.
In `/` there is a Joomla installation and its `.htaccess`.

As first I want to redirect all access on `/sub` to `sub.example.com` and as second all access on `sub.example.com` to `sub.example.com/index.html` due maintenance.

I can redirect all access on `/sub` to `sub.example.com` via

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sub(.*)? http://sub.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

But when I enable the following rule in `/sub/.htaccess` the rule above fails.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.html
RewriteRule .* /index.html
```

I know that's because of the second rewrite in `/sub/.htaccess`, but how can I do the rewrite above?

I tried the following rules in the `/.htaccess` but it does not work

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^sub(.*)? http://sub.example.com$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.html
RewriteRule .* index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in `/sub/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.html index.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: Redirection does not work. Also if I disable Joomla's `.htaccess`